# Populate Grid With List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, c#-4.0, gridview

> public class FinalClass {  public Employee emp{ get; set; }
>
> public Customer cust{ get; set; } }

how to bind `List<FinalClass>` into a Gridview is it possible or  should i have to create a separate class with corresponding fields as its properties?

Please help me out.

Comment: Please tag with relevant programming language etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume based on how the question is phrased that you already know the basics of how databinding works. Within your GridView you can use something like `<%# Eval("Employee.Name") %>`

If you specifically want to know about 2-way databinding then in my opinion it would be easier to create a View-Model, what you refer to as "a separate class with corresponding fields as its properties"